# ColdFusion: how to populate livecycle pdf section dynamically using query data

Tags: coldfusion, cfpdf, cfpdfform

I have a template PDF that has a section that will be laid out like a table.  The data will come from a query.  So this table will be dynamic, number of rows unknown.

How do I accomplish this using ColdFusion?  Is it a combination of creating a template using LiveCycle and creating this section so it is dynamic and then using CFPDF to populate it.

Right now I'm using  to populate static fields.

```
<cfpdfform source="Template.pdf"
   destination="Template2.pdf" action="populate">
   <cfpdfsubform name="form1">
    <cfpdfformparam name="pdf_controlNum" value="123">
    <cfpdfformparam name="pdf_ReportDate" value="05/01/2012">
   </cfpdfsubform>
</cfpdfform>
```

Comment: I do not use LiveCycle, so hopefully someone else can provide more specific instructions. However, from what I have read you must create a dynamic form in LiveCycle. Then loop through the query in your CF code to generate the cfpdfformparam values [as described here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/711389?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: Thanks Leigh, I have looked at the link.  the problem I have is the indexing of the field name.  does the pdf template know the for each row, the field name will be postfixed with '_#id#'

Comment: I am not sure. I got the impression it depends on how the template is structured (and may involve using the `index` attribute too). But that is based on *very* little knowledge of LiveCycle ;-) For the LiveCycle specific portion, you will probably get more timely and accurate answers on the adobe forums.

Comment: I found the solution in following link.  The answer is at bottom of thread.  http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Web_Servers/ColdFusion/Q_26528588.html

Comment: the above link does not seem to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.  It was in this forum:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Web_Servers/ColdFusion/Q_26528588.html

At bottom of thread was this:

2 key points
1. in cf you need to set  overwritedata=”yes” in cfpdfform
2. the pdf needs to be a dynamic pdf.

hope this helps others. I don't have a how to blog but if you know of one just let me know. Very handy indeed.

```
<cfpdfsubform name="details">    
  <cfpdfsubform name="Table1">
    <cfloop from="1" to="#getClientOrderDetails.recordCount#" index="i">            
      <cfpdfsubform name="Row1" index = "#i#">  
      <cfpdfformparam name="pdfDescription" value="#getClientOrderDetails.ItemDescription[i]#">
        <cfpdfformparam name="pdfItemQuantity" value="#getClientOrderDetails.ItemQuantity[i]#">
        <cfpdfformparam name="pdfItemUnitPrice" value="#getClientOrderDetails.ItemUnitPrice[i]#"> 
      </cfpdfsubform>
    </cfloop> 
   </cfpdfsubform>
 </cfpdfsubform>
```

Comment: Glad you solved it! Looks like the main difference is using `index` with the subform. I will tuck that away for future reference. So thanks for posting it.

Comment: also very important, when creating the pdf it needs to be create as a 'dynamic' form.  By default, it is created as 'static.  That was not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just want to create a PDF File? If so you also have to call in the style sheet after the cfdocument

```
<cfdocument 
format="pdf" 
filename = "pdf_file_path\#pdf_controlNum#_#pdf_ReportDate#.pdf"
overwrite = "yes"
marginBottom = ".2"
marginLeft = ".4"
marginRight = ".4"
marginTop = ".2">

<style type="text/css">@import "pdf.css";</style>

QUERY RESULTS TABLES AND CODING HERE ETC

</cfdocument>
```

Comment: No, they are trying to populate an existing pdf *form* ie fill in the fields with values. It is a different ball of wax than creating a pdf from scratch.